# Prevent Spring Schedulers run at the same time

Tags: spring, java-8, scheduler

I have three Spring Schedulers like as shown below

**Scheduler 1 (Runs every 15 min)**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/15 * * * *")
public void scheduler1() {
 // some logic
}
```

**Scheduler 2 (Runs every 20 min)**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/20 * * * *")
public void scheduler2() {
 // some logic    
}
```

**Scheduler 3 (Runs every 25 min)**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/25 * * * *")
public void scheduler3() {
 // some logic
}
```

The schedulers are working fine, but there are times in sometimes they will run at the same time which will create some issues. I would like to know if there is any way in which we can prevent more than one scheduler to execute at a time in Spring

Comment: create a single threaded task executor.

Comment: @zlaval can you show me an example

Comment: You can find anything here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.html

You have to implement the SchedulingConfigurer interface as it was written in the doc and create an Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()